# last 2 versions autoprefixer browserslist

Tags: autoprefixer

I am using autoprefixer and have a `browserslist` file to specify the supported browsers. It looks like this, basically the default plus `iOS 8`:

```
> 1%
Last 2 versions
iOS 8
```

I am wondering can I easily see on [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/) what exact browser versions: `last 2 versions`, `last 3 versions`, `last 4 versions` etc... gives for each individual browser?

Comment: Looks like if I go to http://caniuse.com/#tables it shows the support for `CSS Initial Letter` and in that table gives a full list of browsers. Is this the best way to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use browserl.ist to get the list of browsers satisfying your autoprefixer config, eg. for your case:

http://browserl.ist/?q=%3E+1%25%2C+Last+2+versions%2C+iOS+8